# how is mongodb server name selected?

Tags: mongodb

```
~$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.3
connecting to: test
>
```

why is my server name `test`? and where can I change it?

Comment: That is just the default DB, it actually goes on `localhost` by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'test' is the default database.
You can change current db with the help of use command.

**use** *NewDatabaseName*

If "NewDatabaseName" is not exist it will be created in Mongo.